# Adapter with seekbar and textview

Tags: java, android

I have a listview with a custom adapter that is done with one seekbar and one textview.

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter, null);
        seekBar = (SeekBar)view.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        value = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name);

        seekBar.setMax(200);

        value.setText(myArray[position]+" - "+value);
        seekBar.setProgress(value);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                seek = seekBar.getProgress();
                value.setText(myArray[position]+" - "+progress+" MB");
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

Now, the problem is that when i move the (for example) second seekbar change the text only at the last textview. why? how can i fix this? i want that if i move the second seekbar change the text of the relative textview and not at the last.

Answer (score 0):

Replace first two lines with

```
View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
```

And while initializing the adapter

```
ArrayAdapter<String> languagesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, R.layout.adapter, arrayLanguages)
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the code, the `value` is a member variable, it will always be override by `getView` whenever `getView` is called. That's why your program will update another `TextView` as the `OnSeekBarChangeListener` refer to `value`.

You should use a local variable like this:

```
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        TextView view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter, null);
        SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar)view.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        final TextViewvalue = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name);

        //rest of your code
```